# (Solved) 51% coverage - missing how to test creation of new Task

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, tasks, apexrest

Below Class works great! takes incoming SMS from twilio and responds while creating a new task

My test class is at 51% and I am spinning. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/receiveSMS/*')
global class receiveSMS {
    @HttpGet
    global static void saveSMS() {

        // Store the request received
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

        // Store the HTTP parameters received in a Map
        Map<String, String> smsParams = req.params;
        String fromMobile ;
        String msgBody ;
        Contact contactRecord;


        // Extract SMS Sender's phone number and store it in a variable
        if (smsParams.containsKey('From')){
            fromMobile = smsParams.get('From') ;
        }

        // Extract the body of SMS and store it in a variable
        if (smsParams.containsKey('Body')){
            msgBody = smsParams.get('Body') ;
        }
        string cleanFromNumber = formatPhone(fromMobile);
        // Identify the contact based on Sender's phone number
        // List<Contact> contactRecorded = [Select Id from Contact where MobilePhone = :fromMobile LIMIT 1];
        contactRecord = [Select Id, FirstName from Contact where MobilePhone = :cleanFromNumber LIMIT 1];

        // Create an Activity record on Contact            
        Task newTask = new Task();
        newTask.WhoId = contactRecord.Id ;
        newTask.Subject = 'SMS Received';
        newTask.priority= 'Normal' ;
        newTask.status = 'Completed';
        newTask.description = msgBody ;
        newTask.ActivityDate = System.today() ;
        insert newtask;

        // Set the response values for Web Service
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 200;
        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Thanks '+contactRecord.FirstName+', We have received your SMS') ;
    }

    // Twilio sends the phone number as +15555551234.  We have to reformat the string to (555) 555-1234
    global static String formatPhone(String fromMobile){
        String areaCode = fromMobile.substring(2,5);
        String prefix = fromMobile.substring(5,8);
        String last4 = fromMobile.substring(8);
        String formattedPhone = '(' + areaCode +')' + ' ' + prefix + '-' + last4;
        System.debug('FORMATTED PHONE IS: ' + formattedPhone);
        return formattedPhone;
    }

}
```

Test Class

```java
@isTest
public class TestreceiveSMS{
    public static testmethod void testCallout() {

        RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        receiveSMS classToTest = new receiveSMS();
        req.requestURI = 'https://partial-fastlife.cs95.force.com/services/apexrest/receiveSMS';
        req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response = res;

        receiveSMS.saveSMS();

    }

    static testMethod void test_Contact(){ // This method is supposed to test the contact search and the create new task
        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.MobilePhone = '+15555551234';
        c.FirstName = 'Tom';
        insert c;

         c = [Select Id, FirstName from Contact where MobilePhone = '15555551234' LIMIT 1];

         receiveSMS.saveSMS();

    }

    public static testmethod void testformatPhone() {
        String fromMobile = '+15555551234'; 
        receiveSMS.formatPhone(fromMobile);
    }
}
```

Image of lines of code not covered.

[image]

Comment: *Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is **the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as **[smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests**.* - [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Comment: I recommend you complete all Trailhead modules on Apex unit testing. I have down-voted this post because you do not even indicate which lines are not covered, and do not demonstrate any effort to research this problem yourself. If you **[edit]** your post to improve on these points, I may reverse or at least remove my vote.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, Thanks for the suggestion on showing the failed test lines. As to the Trail heads, done that and more. I can't fined what I am missing there. I am sure its simple.

Comment: The coverage looks a bit off (comments are covered and actual code is ignored?). You might want to re-compile the `receiveSMS` class and run your tests again.

Comment: Surely your test does not pass? You should be getting a null pointer. Please include any error messages verbatim and clearly indicate which line throws them.

Comment: You are right, not sure why I forgot to look at those errors in the test results. its been to long since I worked in APEX.  That's what I was  looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your coverage is low because you are hitting null pointer exceptions. For starters, you need to set `RestContext.request` and its `params` in every test. Don't forget to add assertions.

Once you get past null pointers, you're going to hit a `QueryException` any time your code fails to find a `Contact`. You should query to a list and index in, checking first if it is empty.

Comment: After a liberal use of System.assert and system.debug  (and lots of code editing) I narrowed my issue to my test data. I had the incorrect mobile number format in my test data which resulted in the contactRecord sql to fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final version I will post here, more todo :)  - But for what its worth 100% coverage

Issue was my test data was incorrectly formatted (15555551264 vs (555) 555-1264). This formating was required to take the twilio phone number and reformat it so I could search contacts for a match. That prevented the contactRecord sql in the receiveSMS class from finding my test contact record.

Highly recommend looking at the logs and creating additional assertions and debug logs to help you pinpoint the problem. Adrian Larson's final tip helped remind me of that. Thanks again Adrian Larson for your help!

Updated receiveSMS Class and Test Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/receiveSMS/*')
global class receiveSMS {
@HttpGet
global static void saveSMS() {

   RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

   Map<String, String> smsParams = req.params ;
    String fromMobile ;
   String msgBody ;
   Contact contactRecord;

   if (smsParams.containsKey('From')){
       fromMobile = smsParams.get('From') ;
       system.debug('receiveSMS Class: '+'fromMobile '+ fromMobile);
   }

     if (smsParams.containsKey('Body')){
      msgBody = smsParams.get('Body') ;
        system.debug('receiveSMS Class: '+'msgBody '+ msgBody);
   }
  string cleanFromNumber = formatPhone(fromMobile);
   system.debug('receiveSMS Class: '+ cleanFromNumber +'vs '+fromMobile);
         contactRecord = [Select Id, FirstName, MobilePhone from Contact where MobilePhone = :cleanFromNumber LIMIT 1];

        system.debug('receiveSMS Class: '+'contactRecord '+contactRecord);

   Task newTask = new Task();
   newTask.WhoId = contactRecord.Id ;
   newTask.Subject = 'SMS Received';
   newTask.priority= 'Normal' ;
   newTask.status = 'Completed';
   newTask.description = msgBody ;
   newTask.ActivityDate = System.today() ;
   insert newtask;


   RestContext.response.statusCode = 200;
   RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
   RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Thanks '+contactRecord.FirstName+', We have received your SMS') ;
}

  global static String formatPhone(String fromMobile)
{
    String areaCode = fromMobile.substring(2,5);
    String prefix = fromMobile.substring(5,8);
    String last4 = fromMobile.substring(8);
    String formattedPhone = '(' + areaCode +')' + ' ' + prefix + '-' + last4;
    System.debug('receiveSMS Class: '+'FORMATTED PHONE IS: ' + formattedPhone);
    return formattedPhone;
}
```

}

Test Class:

```
@isTest 
public class TestreceiveSMS{
testmethod public static void testCallout() {

RestRequest req = new RestRequest(); 
RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
receiveSMS classToTest = new receiveSMS();
 req.requestURI = 'https://partial-fastlife.cs95.force.com/services/apexrest/receiveSMS';
req.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.httpMethod = 'GET';
 RestContext.request = req;
    req.addParameter('From', '+15555551264');
    req.addParameter('Body', 'test');
   req.addParameter('To', '+15555551264');
  RestContext.response = res;

       Contact c = new Contact();
    c.MobilePhone = '(555) 555-1264';
    c.FirstName = 'Tom';
    c.LastName = 'Tim';
    insert c;
    system.debug('TestClass: '+c.ID + 'ID '+ c.MobilePhone + ' Mobile Number');
    system.assertEquals('Tim', c.LastName);

  Contact conObj = null;
        List<Contact> resultContact = [Select Id, FirstName, MobilePhone from Contact where MobilePhone =:c.MobilePhone limit 1];
        system.debug('TestClass: '+resultContact);

    if(resultContact.size() > 0){conObj = resultContact.get(0);} 
    system.debug('TestClass: '+'Contact list size = '+resultContact.size());
    system.assertEquals(conObj.ID, c.Id);
    system.debug('TestClass: '+conObj.ID+' TestID'+c.Id);

   receiveSMS.saveSMS();

}
```

}

Comment: FYI you don't have to edit the title of your post to indicate it is solved. Accepting an answer does that. Just curious why you flipped your accepted answer to your own? That green check mark indicates which answer you found most helpful. That certainly could be yours, just not sure if you fully understand the mechanics as a new user. You may find this Meta post informative: **[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)**

Comment: I am new to this, I flipped to my answer only because it was a the final solution. If it makes more sense for this system for me to leave your answer as the final solution then ok, I will switch it back.